# How to hide edges/viewport after import from Warehouse (Sketchup/Collada)

Tags: 3d-view, import, wireframe, collada

I'm trying to use models from 3d Warehouse inside my Blender scene. So I'm downloading them in Collada (.dae) format instead of Sketchup formats since Blender can import dae.

Problem is that they are included with weird black wireframe, even that I have wireframes hidden. I cannot find way to hide it. In render they look ok, just not in viewport.

[image]

Comment: Object Properties > Viewport display > Wireframe

Comment: @Gorgious It's disabled bad lines are still visible. Also it does not look like Blender's wireframe, because lines are cropped and not straight lines like in normal wireframe.

Comment: Have you disabled it for every one of your objects ?

Comment: @Gorgious it's disabled by default. Enabling this option is adding another wireframe on top of it.

Comment: It is due to Sketchup... bad geometry and hard to clean up. But dae export from Sketchup standalone solves the issue. A sketchup importer can be found on the internet but it does not work well with materials.

Comment: I can confirm that the answer given by Coladrop for .dae files does work. If you have a complex model with many parts and don't mind joining them all together first that can make it easier. Also, if you convert the .dae to a .obj, then re-import it to your blend file, you can simply uncheck "Lines" from the "Include" section of the import screen to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had same look with my model when imported .dae
In my case it was textured mesh+ wireframe. So just go to edit mode, and in material properties click on your material and press select (do this with all materials).
After that you should have selected all mesh without wireframe (you can press ctrl+i to invert selection to wireframe and delete it)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do not need this anymore and I cannot check it, but thanks for answer :) My solution at the time was editing .dae in text editor to delete all wireframes whatever they were named in source. I also typed regex for faster search & replace.

Answer (score 0):

Import the file enter *Edit Mode*, at this point Blender automatically selected all of the wireframe as the first thing, just delete it and it's gone.

Alternatively enter *Edit Mode*, select an edge and move it, if it's wireframe you selected then it will stretch without affecting the solid mesh, at this point  <kbd>Click</kbd> it press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Edges*.